# Is there any way to get element info inside the shadow root with Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, web-crawler, shadow-dom

I am trying to scrape some info from a website with java and selenium. However, because of the shadow-root I cannot reach any web element. When i try to get html, it returns empty array. Is there any way to reach the info inside shadow-root or is it impossible?
[html structure of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBfgn.png)

Comment: Can you update the question with the text based formatted relevant HTML, your code trials and the error stack trace please?

Answer (score 3):

You can try JavascriptExecutor to find elements within shadow-root.

```
WebElement rootElement = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", PreRootElement);
```

For details please refer: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Mavni's answer solved the problem for me, but as a refinement I wanted to be able to use a `By` as a locator (e.g. to wait on an `ExpectedCondition`).

```
public class ByShadowRoot extends By {

    @Override
    public WebElement findElement( SearchContext context ) {

        RemoteWebElement element = ( RemoteWebElement ) context;
        JavascriptExecutor driver = ( JavascriptExecutor ) element.getWrappedDriver();
        return ( WebElement ) driver.executeScript( "return arguments[0].shadowRoot" , element );
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements( SearchContext context ) {

        WebElement element = findElement( context );
        return element != null ? Collections.singletonList( element ) : Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "By#shadow-root";
    }
}
```

This was then used like this (this example was used to wait for a ComboBox to pop-up in Vaadin Flow):

```
ByShadowRoot byShadowRoot = new ByShadowRoot();
By comboBoxItem = new ByChained( By.id( "overlay" ) , byShadowRoot , By.id( "content" ) , byShadowRoot , By.id( "selector" ) ,
    By.tagName( "vaadin-combo-box-item" ) );
```

(`ByChained` is in the selenium-support.jar)

A subtlety there was that `By.tagName()` failed if it was immediately after the `byShadowRoot`, with `WebDriverException: unknown error: b.getElementsByTagName is not a function`.  I think this because the `#shadow-root` is just a document fragment in the DOM, as opposed to a document element.